# removing duplicate items java gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable, jcombobox

I am just trying to add some stuff to a combobox here

the thing is that some of the items I'm adding are repeated throughout. The only way I can think of avoiding adding duplicate items to the box is using 1 loop to add all the items to 2 array lists and then another 2 separate loops to loop through both lists to see if any of the items are duplicates (I haven't actually tried this yet so it's possible my logic is wrong).

Can somebody suggest a quick and easy fix?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson that new acronym doesnt exactly roll off the tongue :/

Comment: @Reimeus  I think of it as the name McTare.  Either that or a McDonalds burger, sans the content (more of a McBun, really).

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a `Vector<TableItem>`
2. For each element selected in the table, check [`Vector.contains(tableItem)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

   - If present, do nothing.
   - If not present, add it.
3. Use the `Vector<TableItem>` to establish a `new DefaultComboBoxModel`
4. Call `JComboBox.setModel(ComboBoxModel)`.

Comment: Purely to increase my knowledge, why a Vector as supposed to, well, an ArrayList? Which also has a `contains` method.

Comment: @Gorb Link to the constructor for `DefaultComboBoxModel` that accepts an `ArrayList`..

Answer (score 1):

I like to suggest to add all data got from `JTable` to a `String []` and then check this code:

```
String[] nonduplicate(String[] stData) {

    String[] returnString;
    ArrayList<Stringresult=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList list;

    list = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( stData) );  

    HashSet set = new HashSet( (Collection)list );
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator(); 
    while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        result.add((String) iterator.next()) ;
    }
    returnString=new String[result.size()];
    returnString=result.toArray(returnString);
    return returnString;
}
```

You then have to add this `String[]` to the combo box.